# Added 2nd Apache vhost, original one will not load image(s)

Tags: wordpress, apache, vhosts

I followed the instructions on the Apache web site to add a second vhost to my setup and enable a second Wordpress domain. When I did that, the splash image on the home page of the first one would not load anymore, but everything else worked. Disabling the 2nd vhost made the image appear again. ?? I tried just about everything I could find and think of, nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem was that the person who set up the first Wordpress site modified things with a workaround to refer to that splash image by IP, rather than FQDN on the URL. Since the programmer is on vacation, I added a second ServerAlias on the .conf for that vhost with the IP of the server. That fixed it.